# Usage and docs tag in a component in StencilJS

Tags: stenciljs

StencilJS https://stenciljs.com/

When generating docs-json output for the components, there is a usage (and docs) property for each component but we couldn't find any mention in the documentation about this.

The question: Is the "usage" property for adding a usage example and if so how can it and the "docs" be accessed?

```
{
      "filePath": "src\\components\\my-component\\my-component.tsx",
      "encapsulation": "shadow",
      "tag": "my-component",
      "readme": "# my-component\r\n\r\n\r\n\r",
      "docs": "",
      "docsTags": [],
      "usage": {}, // This property here
      "props": [
        {...
}
```

Comment: In my projects `usage` is always empty. Maybe someone in the [Stencil Slack](https://stencil-worldwide.herokuapp.com/) can help.

Comment: Not sure but have you tried the `@usage` tag in the JSDoc block?

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do it currently seems to be adding .md files in your component/usage folder.

```
  components/
    my-component/
      usage/
        usage-example.md // This is added to usage
        another-example.md
      my-component.css
      my-component.tsx
```